# Symbol for exact division

Tags: symbols

Among many symbols which can be used for the expression "a divides b'', the preferred one is \mid (and its brother \nmid) which has some spacing advantage over \vert. But the double-bar for "a divides exactly b" is normally rendered by \Vert, which has the same spacing problems as \vert. Is there a "double version" of \mid?

[image: Te result of using \vert, \mid and \Vert]

Comment: What's the difference between “divides” and “divides exactly”?

Comment: @egreg: Perhaps `exactly` →there's no remainder? Just a guess

Comment: For me, "a divides exactly b" means that a divides b but the greatest common divisor between a and b/a is 1. This applies particularly well for prime-powers: 3 divides 45, 9 divides 45, 27 does not, so I would write that 3 divides 45 and 9 divides 45 exactly.

Comment: although the name is not even close, `\nparallel` from `amsfonts` is the proper class as well as the proper shape.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use more semantic names, say `\dv` for “divides” and `\edv` for “exactly divides”. The first is easy

```
\newcommand{\dv}{\mid}
```

For the second, we can do

```
\newcommand{\edv}{\mathrel\Vert}
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\dv}{\mid}
\newcommand{\edv}{\mathrel\Vert}

\begin{document}

$3\dv 45$ and $9\edv 45$

\end{document}
```

[image]

There is no `\nedv`, though. We can build it using `picture` mode. There is `\nparallel`, but it's slightly different.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,pict2e}

\newcommand{\dv}{\mid}
\newcommand{\ndv}{\nmid}
\newcommand{\edv}{\mathrel\Vert}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\nedv}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\nedv@\relax}}
\newcommand{\nedv@}[2]{%
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1|$}%
  \setlength{\unitlength}{\dimexpr\ht\z@+\dp\z@}%
  \vcenter{\hbox{%
    \begin{picture}(0.5,1)
    \roundcap
    \put(0.15,0){\line(0,1){1}}
    \put(0.35,0){\line(0,1){1}}
    \put(0,0.4){\line(1,1){0.5}}
    \end{picture}%
  }}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$3\dv 45$ and $9\edv 45$

$10\ndv 45$ and $3\nedv 45$

$\edv$

$\mid$ $\nmid$ $\nedv$ $\nparallel$
\end{document}
```

The last line has a visual comparison between `\mid` (alias `\dv`), `\nmid` (alias `\ndv`), `\nedv` and `\nparallel`. If you think that `\nparallel` suits you, then

```
\newcommand{\nedv}{\nparallel}
```

is sufficient.

[image]

Comment: Great Figaro-etish answer and very _presto_ indeed! I'm of course going to accept this, just one more question: can you explain the role of \mathrel (at least for the non-negated one)? Thanks.

Comment: @FilippoAlbertoEdoardo The difference between `|` and `\mid` is that the latter is essentially `\mathrel{|}`, which affects the spacing, giving it the same role as `=` or `\leq`.

Comment: Yes, this I knew, I ignored the command \mathrel{|}. I guess it defines the variable as being a relation instead of something else, right? Whence de -rel in the name of the command...

Comment: the negation slash looks a bit high to me.  by the way, what about `\nparallel` from 'amssymb` (`amsfonts`)?  why would that not be suitable?  (even if the name is way off.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Of course I forgot about `\nparallel`! On the other hand, the slash on `\nmid` is not in the geometric center of the bar, but a bit higher. It's debatable what to do for negating the double bar.